# Relation between norm and determinant of a linear operator

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, analysis, determinant

Let $A$ be a $n\times n$ matrix and define $T:\mathbb R^n\to \mathbb R^n$ by $T(X)=AX$. Is there a formula that can present the norm $\|T\|$ as the determinant $\det(A)$?

Comment: Do you mean can you write the norm as a function of the determinant? If so, then no.

Comment: Saying the obvious, the matrix $\begin{pmatrix} 1 & -1  \\ 1 & 0  \end{pmatrix}$ has determinant $1$ and it does not preserve norms as the identity matrix does. What do you mean by "present the norm as the determinant"?

Comment: To elaborate on the other comment, note that (for $n\geq 2$) there is a matrix $A\neq 0$ with $\det(A)=0$, but if you could write the norm as a function of the determinant, then $0= \Vert 0\Vert = f(\det 0)=f(0)=f(\det A)=\Vert A\Vert \neq 0$, contradiction.

Comment: Thanks to you all. I mean write the question as a function of the determinant and I got the answer.